# Как делать звонки на андроид без сим

Tags: android, node.js, android-studio, сервер

Добрый день, столкнулся с большой проблемой как для меня, есть программа "мессаджер" он отправляет сообщения через сервер на ноде, есть только те пользователи которые внесены в базу на сервере. А теперь задача, сделать звонки между контактами, вот только номер телефона юзать нельзя! Пробовал через юдп соединение, а на сервер ретранслятор, но не работает. Может еще есть варианты !

Подскажите умные люди, прошу!

Comment: Почему не работает? Должно работать. Попробуйте готовые решения вроде https://github.com/adolfintel/voicechat

Comment: Оно работает очень криво,  коннект не держится совсем. Я и ищу другой вариант кроме юдп